# Why does erasing End-Iterator not give Segmentation Fault with shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, stdvector

The following Code runs without throwing a segemntation fault error. However, the  call to `vec.erase` erases the last element, i.e. removes "pointer 1", reduces the size  of vec by one and leaves "pointer 0" behind.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> vec;
vec.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(0));
vec.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(1));

vec.erase(vec.end());

std::cout << vec.size() << std::endl
```

The same code with just int throws a segmentation fault error, as excpected.

What is the reasons behind this?

PS: Tested with GCC 5.2.1

Comment: you cannot erase `end` from a vector, because it references the element one past the last one. I would guess that it is undefined behavior to do so.

Comment: I know, I do it in this example on purpose. I was surprised, that the undefined behavior differs depending on the content of the vector and not on the container itself.

Comment: thats why they called it "undefined", if you would get predictable behavior it could be defined

Comment: "Undefined behavior" means **only** that the language definition doesn't tell you what a program that uses that code does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The same code with just int throws a segmentation fault error, as expected.

Your expectation is wrong. Undefined Behavior does not guarantee that your program would crash. It could be a surprise for you but behavior is undefined.

Comment: I was surprised, that the undefined behavior differs depending on the content of the vector and not on the container itself.